# Python3/NetworkX. How to find only one single correct path (subgraph) in a graph, by given list of known vertices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, subgraph

The task is:

Given a directed graph with cycles:

```
g = nx.MultiDiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(["<FrFric>","<OpFric>","<OpPull>",'<Spd2>','<Spd1>','<Dist>','<Time>','<Accl>','<Mass>','<FrPull>','<KinEn2>','<KinEn1>','<CfFric>'])
g.add_edges_from([ ("<FrFric>",'<FrPull>'), ("<FrFric>",'<Mass>'), ("<FrFric>",'<Accl>'), ("<FrFric>",'<Cfg>'), ("<FrFric>",'<Mass>'), ("<FrFric>",'<CfFric>'), ("<FrFric>",'<OpFric>'), ("<FrFric>",'<Dist>'),  ("<OpFric>",'<FrFric>'), ("<OpFric>",'<Dist>'), ("<OpFric>",'<OpPull>'), ("<OpFric>",'<KinEn2>'),("<OpFric>",'<KinEn1>'),  ("<OpPull>",'<FrPull>'), ("<OpPull>",'<Dist>'), ("<OpPull>",'<KinEn2>'),("<OpPull>",'<KinEn1>'), ("<OpPull>",'<OpFric>'),  ('<Spd2>','<Spd1>'),('<Spd2>','<Accl>'),('<Spd2>','<Time>'),('<Spd2>','<Dist>'),('<Spd2>','<Spd1>'),('<Spd2>','<KinEn2>'),('<Spd2>','<Mass>'),  ('<Spd1>','<Spd2>'),('<Spd1>','<Accl>'),('<Spd1>','<Time>'),('<Spd1>','<Dist>'),('<Spd1>','<Time>'),('<Spd1>','<Accl>'),('<Spd1>','<Spd2>'),('<Spd1>','<Accl>'),('<Spd1>','<Dist>'),('<Spd1>','<KinEn1>'),('<Spd1>','<Mass>'),  ('<Dist>','<Spd1>'),('<Dist>','<Time>'),('<Dist>','<Accl>'),('<Dist>','<Time>'),('<Dist>','<Spd2>'),('<Dist>','<Spd1>'),('<Dist>','<Accl>'),('<Dist>','<OpPull>'),('<Dist>','<FrPull>'),('<Dist>','<OpFric>'),('<Dist>','<FrFric>'),  ('<Time>','<Spd2>'),('<Time>','<Spd1>'),('<Time>','<Accl>'),('<Time>','<Spd1>'),('<Time>','<Accl>'),('<Time>','<Dist>'),  ('<Accl>','<Spd2>'),('<Accl>','<Spd1>'),('<Accl>','<Time>'),('<Accl>','<Dist>'  ),('<Accl>','<Spd1>'),('<Accl>','<Time>'),('<Accl>','<Spd2>'),('<Accl>','<Spd1>'),('<Accl>','<Dist>'),('<Accl>','<FrPull>'),('<Accl>','<FrFric>'),('<Accl>', '<Mass>'),  ('<Mass>','<FrPull>'),('<Mass>',  '<FrFric>'),('<Mass>',  '<Accl>'),('<Mass>', '<KinEn2>'),('<Mass>',  '<Spd2>'),('<Mass>', '<KinEn1>' ),('<Mass>', '<Spd1>'),('<Mass>','<FrFric>'),('<Mass>',  '<Cfg>'),('<Mass>','<CfFric>'),  ('<FrPull>','<FrFric>'),('<FrPull>',  '<Mass>'),('<FrPull>',  '<Accl>'),('<FrPull>', '<OpPull>'),('<FrPull>',  '<Dist>'),  ('<KinEn2>','<Mass>'),('<KinEn2>',  '<Spd2>'),('<KinEn2>', '<OpPull>'),('<KinEn2>',  '<OpFric>'),('<KinEn2>',  '<KinEn1>'),  ('<KinEn1>','<Mass>'),('<KinEn1>',  '<Spd1>'),('<KinEn1>', '<KinEn2>'),('<KinEn1>',  '<OpPull>'),('<KinEn1>',  '<OpFric>'),  ('<CfFric>','<FrFric>'),('<CfFric>', '<Mass>'),('<CfFric>',  '<Cfg>') ])
```

Known starting vertex for search:

> Frfric

Also known are several vertexes that are contained (must be in) in the path:

> { Dist, KinEn1, KinEn2, FrPull }

It is necessary to somehow go around.. through the least time O (n ^ 2) O (n) O (logn) and derive the correct path! those. it is also necessary to find the connected vertices from which the known vertices come out and to build, as it were, the entire complete chain of path output!

For the FrFric vertex, you should get such a chain of path:

> FrFric => OpFric => OpPull

those, starting with FrFric, we start the search .. we meet Dist from the set of known vertices .. then OpFric - and from it KinEn1, KinEn2 they known and OpPull .. we look at OpPull and from it FrPull and Dist are known! and the answer is received!

those, we went a way - and found there some unknown vertexes that are connected with the known ones and .. If you unroll the whole way, the answer is this:

> FrFric = (((FrPull, Dist), KinEn2, KinEn1), Dist)

And so, how to write such an effective output algorithm ?? in Python3 and NetWorkX!

What are the options??

Comment: Are you trying to traverse the graph and find the way, by starting at a given vertix?

Comment: yes.. 'Frfric' - is a starting vertex..

Comment: This is not the shortest path between two vertices! And not the longest path! 
It must be a uniqal path! only one!
--
I'm trying to get a subgraph or connected component ... But  subgraph that I got contains other vertices that shouldn't be .. The full subgraph (path) should consist of Frfric, OpFric, OpPull and the known vertices outcoming from them